# Why won't my burger menu drop down work using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay, so I am trying to build a navbar for my website. But somehow, my burger-menu won't drop down when I click on it. I am pretty sure it should be an easy fix, but for some reason I just can't find what I did wrong. Here is the file.

I feel like either the HTML file is not connecting to the JS file, or something is wrong with my JS file. Because when I add the class ".mobilenav-active" manually via inspect in the browser, the drop down menu manages to appear. But when I try to do it via JS it just doesn't work.

```js
const burgerMenu = document.querySelector(".burger");
const nav = document.querySelector(".navlinks");

burgerMenu.addEventListener("click", function () {
  nav.classList.toggle(".mobilenav-active");
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montaga&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@700&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Montaga", serif;
  background: #2f3e46;
}
/* NAVBAR */
#navbutton,
#logo,
.navlist,
.nav-a {
  font-family: "Montaga", serif;
  color: #edf0f1;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 10%;
  background: #354f52;
}

#logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
}

#logobutton {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navlinks {
  list-style: none;
}

.navlinks li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.navlinks li a {
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.navlinks li a:hover {
  color: #354f52;
  background: #edf0f1;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

#navbutton {
  padding: 9px 25px;
  background-color: rgba(82, 121, 111, 1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#navbutton:hover {
  background-color: rgba(82, 121, 111, 0.6);
}

.burger .line {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #edf0f1;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
}

/*Navbar's Responsive Breakpoints */

/* Tablet */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  header {
    padding: 30px 3%;
  }

  .navlinks li {
    padding: 0px 10px;
  }

  .navlinks li a:hover {
    color: #354f52;
    background: #edf0f1;
    padding: 5px 5px;
  }
}

/* Mobile */
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  .navlinks {
    position: absolute;
    height: calc(100vh - 100.4px);
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    top: 100.4px;
    background: #354f52;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 100px 0px;
    opacity: 80%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: all 0.5 ease-in;
  }

  .navlinks li a:hover {
    color: #354f52;
    background: #edf0f1;
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }

  /* .navlist {
    opacity: 0;
  } */

  .burger {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .navlinks.mobilenav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    <title>Brian Wyann</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <a id="logobutton" href="index.html">
        <h4 id="logo">BrianWyann</h4>
      </a>
      <nav>
        <ul class="navlinks">
          <li class="navlist"><a class="nav-a" href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="navlist">
            <a class="nav-a" href="./about.html">About Me</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navlist">
            <a class="nav-a" href="./project.html">Projects</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="burger">
          <div class="line"></div>
          <div class="line"></div>
          <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <a href="./contact.html" id="contact"
        ><button id="navbutton">Contacts</button></a
      >
    </header>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: change this to: `nav.classList.toggle("mobilenav-active");` you don't use the period when referencing classList methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using **classList** you don't need to add a dot before class name

```
const burgerMenu = document.querySelector(".burger");
const nav = document.querySelector(".navlinks");

burgerMenu.addEventListener("click", function () {
  nav.classList.toggle("mobilenav-active");
});
```

*classList* expects a class, by adding a dot it adds the dot in the class name as well